# Asp Net Core Correlation failed when using Azure B2B

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid

I've been using Azure B2B provider for months now and recently I had to create a new directory. In this directory I'm facing the following problem:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
Exception: Correlation failed.
Unknown location

Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler<TOptions>.HandleRequestAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

My OpenId configuration (It's not reaching OnAuthorizationCodeReceived):

```cs
public void Configure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
            {
                options.ClientId = azureOptions.ClientId;
                options.Authority = azureOptions.Authority + "/v2.0/";
                options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
                options.CallbackPath = azureOptions.CallbackPath;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.ClientSecret = azureOptions.ClientSecret;

                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;

                options.ResponseType = "id_token code";

                options.Scope.Add("email");
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

                // Subscribing to the OIDC events
                options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived;
            }
```

Any idea how to solve that?

Thanks!